# How can one prove (¬ ∀ x, p x) → (∃ x, ¬ p x) from first principles in LEAN?

Tags: theorem-proving, lean

The proof of this basic implication from first principles, an exercise in "Theorem proving in Lean" 4.4, beats all my attempts so far:

```
open classical
variables (α : Type) (p q : α → Prop)
variable a : α

local attribute [instance] classical.prop_decidable
theorem T08R : (¬ ∀ x, p x) → (∃ x, ¬ p x) := 
begin
    intro nAxpx, 
    --by_contradiction nExnpx,
    --apply nAxpx,
end
```

After the `intro` I don't know how to use `nAxpx` to go further. I thought of `by_contradiction`, but that only introduces the negated existence `nExnpx`, which can't be used with `cases`, so I can't produce an `x : α`. Excluded middle doesn't seem to help either. I can get a proof with `mathlib` tactics,

```
theorem T08R : (¬ ∀ x, p x) → (∃ x, ¬ p x) := 
begin
    push_neg,
    tauto
end
```

but don't have enough knowledge to translate that back into tactics mode, so this doesn't help my understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to do `by_contradiction` twice. After `apply naXpx` try `intro a` and then `by_contradiction`. Then you'll have an `a` a proof of `¬p a`, but also a proof that `¬∃ (x : α), ¬p x` which is a contradiction.

A full proof is

```
theorem T08R : (¬ ∀ x, p x) → (∃ x, ¬ p x) := 
begin
    intro nAxpx, 
    by_contradiction nExnpx,
    apply nAxpx,
    assume a,
    by_contradiction hnpa,
    apply nExnpx,
    existsi a,
    exact hnpa,
end
```

Comment: Tricky! Don't we think of this as a tautology, ever after learning that `(¬ ∀ x, p x)` is equivalent to `(∃ x, ¬ p x)`? Super helpful.